# behat predefined steps

Tags: php, behat, phar

has anybody encountered the following problem: behat apparently works fine, but it has no predefined steps: the result of

```
\tests> php .\behat\behat.phar -di
```

is empty even the file FeatureContext.php has no steps defined.
My behat version is 2.4.0, it has been istalled with the help of PHAR,  PHP Version is 5.4.9. 
Below are some details of my installation. The tree structure is as follows:

```
tests> dir
Directory: xxx\tests
Mode      Name                                       
d----     behat                                   
d----     features                                   
-a---     bootstrap.php                                   
-a---     phpunit.xml                                   
-a---     WebTestCase.php
```

behat folder contains the following files:

```
tests> dir .\behat
Directory: xxx\tests\behat
Mode       Name
-a---     behat.phar                                   
-a---     mink.phar                                   
-a---     mink_extension.phar
```

while feature folder has only bootstrap directory

```
   tests> dir .\features
Directory: xxx\tests\features
    Mode     Name
    d----   bootstrap
```

which contains the only file FeatureContext.php with the following content

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
    Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
    Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

class FeatureContext extends BehatContext
{
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your context here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behat itself **doesn't come** with any predefined steps.

I can see you downloaded the mink extension and I'm guessing you're looking for steps which come with it (they're defined in the *MinkContext*). You didn't paste your *behat.yml* so I'm not sure if you actually enabled the extension. For more details follow [the official docs](http://extensions.behat.org/mink/index.html).

*Note*: Steps defined in the *MinkContext* are a good start but once you finish playing with Behat, you should rather start writing your own steps and use the language of your business domain. Default *MinkContext* steps hardly ever reflect one's domain language.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right. The point was that I had not make behat see mink extension due to some inconsistencies in my behat.yml file. Now I cloned [link](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension-example) with proper example and finally made it work.